# Integrating a relational database with fingerprint reader

Tags: templates, sdk, storage, fingerprint, reader

Language: C#

Type of program: WinForms

Fingerprint Reader: ZK4500

Do I have the SDK? Yes

Ok, so I have Installed the  SDK, and referenced ZKFPEngXControl in my code.

I know how to write to a database and query.

My question is about how to go about using the data I can get from this fingerprint reader and storing it in a way that I can authenticate using a fingerprint.

With regards to the process that I will need to follow, I have a couple of scenarios working in my head that Im not sure are even close.

1) Do I need to store a registration fingerprint image, then when I need to compare with the currently scanned fingerprint, convert both to fingerprint templates, compare them, then proceed with the rest of the logic..... or

2) capture registration fingerprint, convert it to fingerprint template, store the template, capture current fingerprint, convert to template, compare with stored template.

3) I am completely off track

I also have a side question about the fingerprint template... Does a fingerprint template take data from multiple fingerprints or just one fingerprint?

Comment: I made the changes you requested @Cœur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution with this was to save a fingerprint template to my DB. I could compare the saved fingerprint template to the current scanned fingerprint template.

Also it is possible to create a template from multiple fingerprints, with the sdk I am using, you just use the Enroll methods. This said however, you can just use one fingerprint to create a template.